# Xcode playground prints wrong date value despite showing the correct value in the sidebar

Tags: swift, xcode, date

After creating `DateComponents()` and fetching the `Calendar.current` and the `Date()`, I altered some date components and created a new date variable based on the altered components. The value of this variable displays correctly in the sidebar on Xcode playground but when I print this value it shows the wrong date. The same happens in the app code too (i.e. not just in the Playground).

```
// Initial set-up
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

// Getting some components
var month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
var year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
var day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)

// Some sample code
if day > 15 {
    day = 1
    if month != 12 {
        month += 1
    } else {
        month == 1
    }
} else {
    day = 15
}

// Create date from components
// Generic
dateComponents.hour = 00
dateComponents.minute = 00

// Specific
dateComponents.day = day
dateComponents.month = month
dateComponents.year = year

// Finalise the next resetDate
let resetDate = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)

resetDate // Displays correct value in the side bar

print(resetDate!) // Prints wrong value
```

The expected result of course is that the value of `resetDate` in both the last two lines should agree. On 31 August 2019 this is what I get in the sidebar:

```
"Sep 1, 2019 at 12:00 AM"
```

versus what the `print` statement displays:

```
2019-08-31 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: It's correct.Your time zone is +0530 and `print` shows dates in UTC. `2019-08-31 18:30:00 +0000` and `2019-09-01 00:00:00 +0530` is the same point in time.

Comment: You’re right. This is embarrassing. I should’ve thought of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output is correct. Please note that print date object direct alway received result on timezone +0 UTC. In your brain, just plus with your timezone is time in your timezone.